# MySQL create and use new database with variable

Tags: mysql

I want to create and use a database/schema by using a variable, so I can change it when I want to run a script on a different Schema.

I have something like this:

```
SET @VarSchema = 'test';
SET @Front = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ';
SET @EndPart = ';';
SET @Stmt = CONCAT(@Front,@VarSchema,@EndPart);
PREPARE stmt FROM @Stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;

SET @Front = 'USE ';
SET @EndPart = ';';
SET @Stmt = CONCAT(@Front,@VarSchema,@EndPart);
PREPARE COMMAND FROM @Stmt;
EXECUTE COMMAND;
```

But this gives me this error: `Error Code: 1295. This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`

EDIT: It complains about this statement:

```
SET @Front = 'USE ';
SET @EndPart = ';';
SET @Stmt = CONCAT(@Front,@VarSchema,@EndPart);
PREPARE COMMAND FROM @Stmt;
EXECUTE COMMAND;
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Which statement is it complaining about?

Comment: The second one, ill edit it to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't execute the `USE` statement with a prepared statement, you'll have to prepare all your queries so you can substitute the database name into them.

Comment: It does seem like a strange limitation, but if this is the way I have to do it, then i shall do it like that. Thanks!